# Windows Phone SMB client

Tags: windows-phone-7, network-protocols, smb

I'm considering to improve my freeware WP7 radio application by allowing user to record the radio.

How can I copy data from WP7's isolated storage to NetBIOS share on a Windows PC?

Is there anything (technical or legal) that forbids implementing [SMB V2 protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#SMB2) according to [the Microsoft's specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246482.aspx) on the top of .NET TCP socket on Windows Phone platform?

Comment: If you have at least, Windows Phone 8, I could answer this.

Answer (score 0):

[Samba](https://www.samba.org/) has implemented SMB/CIFS and it is open source. I assume it should be perfectly okay if you will implement it too..